# Custom layout when viewing instant search results

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

View layouts can be defined and are remembered for each mail folder. Is there a way to set a dedicated view layout to be used for search results, only?

Specifically, I would want to see the "*In Folder*" column when (and only when) multi-folder search results are displayed, since the column is pointless for single-folder views and is a waste of space in that case.

Comment: I am afraid there is no built-in method for this. You can filter the results By Folder as a workaround. Besides, it is suggested to share your feedback via the Outlook UserVoice forum.https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: @Aidan I did in fact upvote these [related](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/12263871-option-to-display-folder-of-email-after-search) [entries](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/18433378-provide-an-option-to-display-the-folder-name-in-wh) on UserVoice, though past history makes me skeptical that anyone at MS even reads those at all.